# Plotting a Maximum and Minimum

Tags: matlab

```
plot(timevec,fuelCost,'-k')
grid on
xlabel('Time(days)');
ylabel('Amount of Money Spent ($)');
title({'Plant Production Cost';'01 April 2013 - 30 April 2013'})
```

If I am plotting this graph, how would I go about plotting the maximums and minimums contained in the plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `fuelcost` is a single vector of data (i.e. not a multi-column matrix) , and you want horizontal lines across the whole span of the data, then after your current lines, use,

```
timespan = [min(timevec) max(timevec)]; % or timespan = xlim(gca);
line(timespan,[1 1]*max(fuelCost),'Color',[1 0 0]);
line(timespan,[1 1]*min(fuelCost),'Color',[0 1 0]);
```

If you only want dots at the correct points on the plot, then after your current lines, use,

```
[max_val,i_max] = max(fuelCost);
[min_val,i_min] = min(fuelCost);
line(timevec([i_min,i_max]),[min_val,max_val],'Marker','.','Linestyle','none','Markersize',10);
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I need to plot these with a point, not a line.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you want to plot only maximum and minimums of if you simply want to highlight them inside the existing plot... but I think this should be fine for your needs:

```
vec = randi([20 50],100,1);
vec_len = numel(vec);
vec_seq = 1:vec_len;

val_max = max(vec);
vec_max = nan(vec_len,1);
vec_max(vec == val_max) = val_max;

val_min = min(vec);
vec_min = nan(vec_len,1);
vec_min(vec == val_min) = val_min;

plot(vec_seq,vec,'-k');
hold on;
grid on;
plot(vec_seq,vec_max,'.r','Markersize',25);
plot(vec_seq,vec_min,'.b','Markersize',25);
hold off;
```

You shoud not have problems modifying the code above in order to adapt it to your current framework, since it's very basic. This is the output:

[image: Output]